# Wordpress add_options_page() function not considering role

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress plugin development and i am stuck at why the wordpress function `add_options_page()` is not accepting role.

This is my code which is not working

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'ct_admin_settings_page');
function ct_admin_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page(
        'CT Settings',
        'CT Settings',
        'Administrator',
        'ct_admin_settings',
        'ct_admin_settings_page'
    );
}
```

but if i try the following, the menu appears (changing **Administrator** to **manage_options**),

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'ct_admin_settings_page');
function ct_admin_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page(
        'CT Settings',
        'CT Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'ct_admin_settings',
        'ct_admin_settings_page'
    );
}
```

It is my understanding that the third parameter in function `add_options_page` is [ROLE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) so why Administrator which is a ROLE not being accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the third parameter of the [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) function is a `capability` which is different than a `role`.

Another way to think of it is to say, "A **role** can *do* these X number of things called **capabilities**. Some capabilities are 'doable' by several roles."

Taking a look at the function signature from the documentation we can see they've defined the parameter name to be `capability`.

```
<?php
add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
?>
```

I would take a look at [this chart of Roles & Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) and choose a *capability* that only an Administrator would have (preferably one **closely related** to the feature you're building in your plugin).

For example, I might choose `manage_options` (just as you've done) as it reflects fairly closely what you're trying to build `ct_admin_settings_page` to do.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now.